# Remove datetetime object from variable and convert to string

Tags: python, json

Here is the example data I am working with as a data frame and as a json type:

```
d = {'mw': [600], 'datetime': ["2002-01-01"]}
json_data = {'mw': 600, 'datetime':["2002-01-01"]}
```

I want to export json_data via json.dump. However, when I export the file I get the error:

```
with open(dir_path + '/Visualizations/json/' + 'gen_type_box.json', 'w') as outfile:
json.dump(json_data, outfile)

TypeError: Object of type 'Timestamp' is not JSON serializable
```

So, I proceed to turn the column that causes the problem into a string in the initial data frame and turn it into a JSON again with:

```
d['datetime'] = d.index
d['datetime_str'] = d['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

And remove the old 'datetime' variable so that there is no way JSON can get confused:

```
d = d[['mw','datetime_str']]
```

However, when I print out the variable d['datetime_str'] to see if it works it still looks like a datetime variable AND it still gives me the same error! Why can't I turn this datetime variable into a string? What am I missing?

**EDIT: Solved with the answer below **

I used the answer below to solve the problem which worked great. Then I had several other errors related to numpy ints. The 'mw' variable in the example data frame was a "numpy.int64" and so I used "np.asscalar()" to make sure I had Python ints that JSON could work with.

Comment: try this, resource_groups2_sub['datetime_str']=resource_groups2_sub['datetime'].astype(str)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
a = {'event': 'login', 'times_stamp': datetime.today()}
print(a)

a['times_stamp'] = a['times_stamp'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(a)
with open('try_file.json', 'w') as ffp:
    json.dump(a, ffp)
    ffp.flush()
ffp.close()
```

Output:

```
{'event': 'login', 'times_stamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 13, 11, 8, 39, 998022)}
{'event': 'login', 'times_stamp': '2018-06-13'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Could you please explain a bit more with dummy data, how you are exactly approaching the issue?

Comment: Umesh Kaushik - why doesn't strftime() work when I tried to do it on the initial data frame? It only worked when creating the JSON. Thx!

Comment: Hi, @d.leon I executed the program on the json_data variable you posted in the question and it worked and date there is already in string format. Could you please tell what is the datatype of the structure you were using?